# Inverse of a multivariable function $f : I \times J \to \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Let $f : (-1/2, 1/2) \times [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a function such that $$f(x,\theta) = \big(1 + x \cos(\theta/2), 0, x \sin(\theta/2)\big) $$

Is $f$ invertible? If yes, what's the inverse?

My answer: $f$ is invertiable, it's injective on its domain and surjective on its image $f(D)$ and that the inverse is $$f^{-1}(x,y,z) = \bigg(\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + z^2}, \ 2 \tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{z}{x-1}\Big)\bigg)$$

Is this correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is not injective.

For any value of $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, we have $f(0,\theta)=(1,0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it is invertible, what is the inverse image of $(0,1,0)$? That is, for what values of $x$ and $\theta$ will
$$
f(x,\theta) = (0,1,0)$$

Obviously there are no such values so the function is not invertible.

If you said, instead, that the function mapped $(-1/2,1/2)$ to the subset of $\Bbb R^3$ that has $y=0$ (in the same way as before), then that function is invertible. But that is not the same function; the space used as the range is different.

Comment: I was actually considering that: it's surjective on $xz$-plane. But there's also a problem when $x = 0$ (quasi's answer)